# How to access value from json decode array

Tags: javascript, php, json

**JSON decode :**

```
$test=json_decode($tableData,TRUE);
```

The result of this was:

```
 [{
    "IngredientName": "Sunflower",
    "Quantity": "6",
    "Free_Quantity": "0",
    "Rate": "6"
}, {
    "IngredientName": "ganapathi",
    "Quantity": "6",
    "Free_Quantity": "0",
    "Rate": "6"
}]
```

How do I access the `IngredientName` from each element of the result array, using a `for..each` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$test=json_decode($tableData);
foreach($test as $arr) {
  echo $arr->IngredientName."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of decoding a JSON is an array of arrays. You can iterate through them the following way:

```
$test=json_decode($tableData,TRUE);
foreach($test as $ingredient) {
  echo $ingredient['IngredientName'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a working approach:

```
<?php
$encoded = '[{"IngredientName":"Sunflower","Quantity":"6","Free_Quantity":"0","Rate":"6"},{"IngredientName":"ganapathi","Quantity":"6","Free_Quantity":"0","Rate":"6"}]';
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);

foreach ($decoded as $object) {
  var_dump($object->IngredientName);
}
```

The obvious output is:

```
string(9) "Sunflower"
string(9) "ganapathi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
foreach($tableData as $value){
echo json_decode($value['IngredientName']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=json_decode($tableData,TRUE);  
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     echo $value['IngredientName'] . '<br />';
}
```